# Pandas dict application over several columns, handling non matches values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, apply

I have a dataframe like:

```
ìmport pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
       "age" : [20,22,20,23],
       "name" : ["A","B","C","A"],
       "addres" : ["add1","add2","add3","add4"],
       "job" :  ["C","E","C","D"],
       "score" : [0.44,0.43,0.25,0.36]
     })
categors = ["name","addres","job"]
```

```
df:

       age name addres job  score
    0   20    A   add1   C   0.44
    1   22    B   add2   E   0.43
    2   20    C   add3   C   0.25
    3   23    A   add4   D   0.36
```

and I have a dict like this:

```
mapping_dict = {
    "name" : {"A":0, "B": 1},
    "addres" : {"add1": 0, "add2": 1, "add3":2},
    "job" : {"A":0, "B":1, "C": 2, "D":3}
    }
```

I would likt to apply this dictionary to their match column, so I can do this:

```
df[categors].replace(mapping_dict,inplace=True)
```

or

```
df[categors] = df[categors].replace(mapping_dict)
```

it's the same because they return the same problem:

```
      name addres job
    0    0      0   2
    1    1      1   E
    2    C      2   2
    3    0   add4   3
```

The problem is that non matched values (like `add4` in column `addres` or `C` in column `name` or `E` in column `job`) are not handled to be replaced with any argument of `.replace` function. I need those values to be mapped to `-1`

So, to achieve this, we can make a loop:

```
for column in categors:
    df[column] = df[column].map(mapping_dict[column])

df
   age  name  addres  job  score
0   20   0.0     0.0  2.0   0.44
1   22   1.0     1.0  NaN   0.43
2   20   NaN     2.0  2.0   0.25
3   23   0.0     NaN  3.0   0.36
```

and solve NaN with `.fillna(-1)` or better one

```
 for column in categors:
     l = lambda x: mapping_dict[column].get(x,-1)
     df[column] = df[column].apply(l)
 df 
        age  name  addres  job  score
    0   20     0       0    2   0.44
    1   22     1       1   -1   0.43
    2   20    -1       2    2   0.25
    3   23     0      -1    3   0.36
```

So, I know how to do the stuff, this has been proved.

My problems are:

- 1. I don't think that pandas was made to loop over columns, but vectorized functions applications over columns.
- 2. My real dataframe is large enought to need a vectorized function, and `mapping_dict` is large enough too.

So, If I could use `apply` with `axis=1` and get the column name `column_name` somehow like `pandas.Series.column_name`, I could do something like :

```
df[columns].apply(lambda x: mapping_dict[x.column_name].get(x,-1) , axis=1)
```

By now, I think that an inherited class who owns from `pandas.dataframe` all its properties and adds `x.column_name` is the "Cannon to kill a mosquito"  solution.

So do you know any **fast, one line** solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a "catch-all" to the end of the dict for each column. This was anything not matched becomes `-1`:

```
mapping_dict = {
    "name" : {"A":0, "B": 1, ".*":-1},
    "addres" : {"add1": 0, "add2": 1, "add3":2, ".*":-1},
    "job" : {"A":0, "B":1, "C": 2, "D":3, ".*":-1}
}
```

Then just include the `regex` parameter in your replace.

```
df.replace(mapping_dict, inplace=True, regex=True)

   age  name  addres  job  score
0   20     0       0    2   0.44
1   22     1       1   -1   0.43
2   20    -1       2    2   0.25
3   23     0      -1    3   0.36
```

Comment: so, I need a multiple insert on whole dict `mapping_dict`. Humm some fast code?

Comment: If you are concerned about the time it takes to add the `,".*":-1` just use a simple regex or  find/replace in a text editor. All `}` become `,".*":-1 }`

Comment: Nope, I just solve it smarter. This is for a predict function (changing categorical data to numeric one), so in my preprocessing part I used to save and initialize the dict with `categors_dict = dict()`. Now I just changed this line to `categors_dict= {".*":-1}`